# How to connect reCaptcha v3 and Image verification grid

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I would want to understand when **reCaptcha v3** uses the **image verification grid** (with those semaphores) if I have configured my score under certain value. Actually when I implement reCaptcha v3 I can get a response  array with success and score parameters. but I don't have a trigger to invoke the image verification grid. Is there some way to do that?

My learning source was https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Answer (score 1):

reCaptcha V3 does not have image grid verification of its own, You can achieve that with recaptcha v2, you can configure it be be usually hidden and when a bot is detected you get the image verification grid.
if you want to still use V3, when you detect a low score trigger a v2.